# Custom color picker for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, colors, color-picker

I was looking for a color picker for iPad/iPhone. I checked everything from cocoacontrols but none of them matched my requirement. I don't like a color wheel or any control which takes the whole iPhone screen. I need something similar to this,

[image]

I found [this article](http://icrglabs.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/color-picker-for-iphoneipad/) pretty useful.

But it's a PNG image based color picker. I need more accurate picker. Is there any open source control which is similar to this? If not I would like to write a custom picker myself but can someone point me in to a direction on where should I begin with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write your own. It's a very simple control.

Subclass [`UIControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
 Implement drawRect: to draw the [color gradient](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadings/dq_shadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH207-TPXREF101).
 Add a [`UIPanGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or implement the [touch handling](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW9) methods.
 Call `[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` whenever the selected color changes.

Answer (score 1):

[SwiftColorPicker](https://github.com/MrMatthias/SwiftColorPicker) Has a HuePicker Control you can use it to get a hue value and construct a color with

```
UIColor(hue: picker.h, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
```